# Django - How To Make Migrations For Reusable App

Tags: python, django

I generally use django as a full-blown web app, and am now attempting to make my first pull request on a reusable application. I normally create migrations like this:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

Of course, since this is a reusable application there is no `manage.py` file. Even if I add one, there is no `settings.py` file to point the `manage.py` to.

What is the accepted way to create migrations for a reusable django application?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that there IS a `settings.py` file in each application, I just overlooked it.

Comment: Is there a `SECRET_KEY` setting inside? There shouldn't be, but I'm getting error that I don't have one.